# Issue with my parsing algorithm (java)

Tags: java, parsing, matrix

I'm trying to write a simple parsing algorithm to parse the following data:

Input:

```
3 9 6

1 1 1.0
1 2 2.0
1 3 3.0
2 1 4.0
2 2 5.0
2 3 6.0
3 1 7.0
3 2 8.0
3 3 9.0

1 1 1.0
1 3 1.0
2 2 1.0
3 1 1.0
3 2 1.0
3 3 1.0
```

EXPECTED Output:

```
A has 9 non-zero entries: 
1: (1, 1.0) (2, 2.0) (3, 3.0) 
2: (1, 4.0) (2, 5.0) (3, 6.0) 
3: (1, 7.0) (2, 8.0) (3, 9.0) 

B has 5 non-zero entries: 
1: (1, 1.0) (3, 1.0) 
3: (1, 1.0) (2, 1.0) (3, 1.0)
```

The first line provides the following data: 3 = size of Matrix (3 x 3), 9 = number of non-zero values for the first matrix, and 6 = number of values of the second matrix. The next 9 set of lines are the values to be entered in the first matrix. The last 6 lines are the values to be entered in the second matrix. The program parses the first line, the 9 values of the first matrix, and the 6 values of the second matrix, HOWEVER my program never terminates and gets stuck in a continuous loop and I can't understand why, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Sparse{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
     Scanner in = null;
     PrintWriter out = null;
     String line = null;
     String[] token = null;
     int i, j, k, n = 0;
     int lineNumber = 0;
     double x = 0;

     if(args.length < 2){
        System.out.println("Usage: FileIO infile outfile");
        System.exit(1);
     }

     in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
     out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(args[1]));

     int size = in.nextInt();
     int nnzA = in.nextInt(); 
     int nnzB = in.nextInt();
     Matrix A = new Matrix(size); 
     Matrix B = new Matrix(size);

     in.nextLine();

     for (i = 0; i < nnzA; i++){
         j = in.nextInt();
         k = in.nextInt();
         x = in.nextDouble();
         A.changeEntry(j,k,x);
     }

     in.nextLine();

     while (in.hasNextLine()){
        if (in.hasNext()){
           j = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
           k = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
           x = Double.parseDouble(in.next());
           B.changeEntry(j,k,x);
        }else{
           in.close();
           break;
        }
     }

     out.println("A has " + A.getNNZ() + " non-zero entries:");
     out.println(A);

     out.println("A has " + B.getNNZ() + " non-zero entries:");
     out.println(B);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger !

Comment: You should be able to easily determine where the infinite looping occurs. Please provide this information.

Comment: Please stick to Java naming conventions, variables are in `camelCase`. There is no need to declare variables at the top of the method - declare them _where they are used_, for example; in the case of `i`,`j`,`k` declare them in the loops. This will make your code much easier to read.

Comment: updated code, but still have issues.

Comment: does program terminate when you press <ENTER> twice at the end?

Comment: No it doesn't. I'm running this on a UNIX server, only crtl^z stops it.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the issue wasn't in my parsing but in one of my toString method for printing the matrices. The parsing function works no problem now, (I did switch back to using a for loop instead of a while loop on the second loop.).